# Can't remove index.php from URL

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to remove index.php from URL, but I keep getting error 404.
Config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]` - change last line and try.

Comment: Just a tip in codeigniter 3 and up versions you must set your base url.

Comment: See this helper link may it helps [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite)

Comment: Is your install on a lampp/xampp or on a live server?

Answer (score 2):

You need one more .htaccess file in your application folder, and here is the detail of the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please copy and paste following code in your htaccess file and put it in **root folder and application folder**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```